# PHP preg_split (with the delimiter included)

Tags: php, regex

I was trying to include the delimiter while using `preg_split` but was unsuccessful.

```
print_r(preg_split('/((?:fy)[.]+)/', 'fy13 eps fy14 rev', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

I'm trying to return:

```
array(
    [0] => fy13 eps
    [1] => fy14 rev
)
```

With the flags parameter set to `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`:

> If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.

The `fy` is in parenthesis, so I don't know why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current approach isn't working because "parenthesized expression" here is referring to capturing groups, and the `?:` to start your group makes it a non-capturing group.  So you can get the `fy` included by changing your expression to `/(fy)/`, however I don't think this is what you want because you will get an array that contains `fy`, `13 eps`, `fy`, and `14 eps` (the parenthesized expressions are separate entries in the result).

Instead, try the following:

```
print_r(preg_split('/(?=fy)/', 'fy13 eps fy14 rev', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

This uses a lookahead to split just before each occurrence of `fy` in your string.

Answer (score 0):

With the example you gave, I am not sure that you really need to use the *preg_split* function. For example you can obtain the same with *preg_match_all* in a more efficient way (from the perspective of performance):

```
preg_match_all('/fy(?>[^f]++|f++(?!y\d))*/', 'fy13 eps fy14 rev', $results);
print_r($results);
```

The idea here is to match `fy` followed by all characters but `f` one or more times or `f` not followed by `y` all zero or more times.

More informations about `(?>..)` and `++` respectively:

1. [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html%E2%80%8E) for atomic groups
2. and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html%E2%80%8E) for possessive quantifiers